# Decoding the multiple barcodes on the image which was picked from the phone's gallery

Tags: android

Am trying to decode the multiple barcodes found on the image which is picked from the gallery,
but its not returning any data about the barcodes. Here is the my code snippet....
the following code picks the image from gallery and tries to decode them.
please suggest me the best way that i can succeed my requirements.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
        LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        try {
             Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
             Global.text = result.getText(); 
                byte[] rawBytes = result.getRawBytes(); 
                BarcodeFormat format = result.getBarcodeFormat(); 
                ResultPoint[] points = result.getResultPoints();
                tv1.setText(Global.text);
                tv2.setText("FORMAT: " + format);

        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ChecksumException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();


        }   


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi guys, can anyone please comment on my question...........

Comment: Hi Sean, is that my question clear? please suggest me some solution...